# How can I get Nodes and Links after being edited on the DiagramEditor?

Tags: flex4, ilog, ilog-elixir

In flex, I use IBM ilog Elixir to display network topology graph.

I maintain an xml file which in turn populates nodes and links arraycollections for Diagram to display.

Now, through Diagram Editor I perform some modification on diagram and hit save. I want to get all the nodes and links on editor to modify xml file while saving.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from other forum.

diagram.Graph gives us whole graph currently held in underlying Diagram.
so, now you can access graph.nodes and graph.links to get edited values.